# replacing "\"" by empty character

Tags: c, linux

I need to replace " (ASCII value 34) char by empty character "".

In output, instead of quote i get an "?" question mark character.
I tried to use things like:

```
mystring[itit] = "";

mystring[itit] = '';

mystring[itit] = "\O";
```

My code:

```
strcpy( mystring ,op->data.value.str  );
          for(itit=0;itit<10;itit++)
          {
            if(mystring[itit] == 34)
            {
              mystring[itit] = NULL;
            }


          }
          printf( "%s\n",mystring);
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

For clarification: the strings in mystring are like:

"hello"

"place "

"school"

all with the quotation marks - I Actually need to remove them and get:

hello

place

school

Comment: Why do you think using a `\0` in a C string before the end is OK? `\0` is the Terminator in C. It signals the end of the string.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you want to remove the quotation character from the string rather than replace it with something?

Comment: Yeah i actually need to remove it.

Comment: A character is a character. There is no "empty" character. You can just delete a character. And a string literal is not a character constant.

Comment: `""` is a `const char *` to a string that actually looks like this: `{'\0'}`. Replace with `'\0'` (which will terminate the string), or simply `0`. But what you really want to do is _move_ the remainder of the string by -1 position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is remove the character, not replace it, since you're not replacing it with anything.  To do this, when you find the character is question, you need to move the remaining characters down.

```
int i,j;

strcpy(mystring, "aa\"bb\"cc");
for(i=0,j=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(mystring[i] != '"')
    {
        mystring[j] = mystring[i];
        j++;
    }
}
mystring[j] = '\0';
printf("mystring=%s\n",mystring);
```

Result:

```
mystring=aabbcc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int removeChar(char *str, char c) {

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0, j = 0 ; str[i] ; i++){
        if( str[i] == c) continue;     // skip c do not copy it
        str[j] = str[i];              // shift characters left
        j++;
    }
    str[j]=0; // terminate the string
    return j;  // return the actual size
}
```

Comment: Probably clearer than my solution for a beginner as it's not so reliant on pointer "arithmetic". Plus one.

Answer (score 2):

To *remove* a character from a string, you can do this:

```
void remove(char* str, char rm)
{
    char *src, *dst;
    for (src = dst = str; *src != '\0'; ++src) {
        *dst = *src;
        if (*dst != rm) ++dst;
    }
    *dst = '\0'; /*insert terminator at the new place*/
}
```

and call with `rm` equal to 34.

This algorithm is well-known; I've adopted it from Kernighan & Ritchie. Do study it carefully with your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are simply arrays of characters with a NUL (0) at the end. (They cannot contain NULs.) As with any array, you can't simply "remove" an element. You need to shift all the following elements one position, with the result that there will be an unneeded element at the end. With strings this extra element isn't a huge problem becauyse the NUL still identifies where the string ends.

In this case, you are copying the string first, so you might as well copy it without the characters you want to delete. Unless you know how many such characters there are, you will need to have allocated enough space in the new string for the entire string you want to copy:

```
/* Before this, you must ensure that mystring has enough space */
{
  char* out = mystring;
  const char* in = op->data.value.str;
  do {
    if (*in != '"') *out++ = *in;
  } while (*in++);
}
```

Note: I use the fact that strings are NUL-terminated to terminate the loop, which saves me from having to know in advance how long `op->data.value.str` is. For this reason, I use character *pointers* rather than indexes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "empty character". A string can be empty by having no characters, but a character is an atomic element and can't be empty, like a box of apples can be empty, but one can't have an "empty apple".

Instead, you need to remove the quotes and close the space they took up. Better yet, if you do the copying yourself, just don't copy them:

```
char *psrc = op->data.value.str;
char *pdest = mystring;

while (*psrc != '\0')
{
    if (*psrc != '\"') 
    {
        *pdest = *psrc;
        ++pdest;
    }
    ++psrc;
}
*pdest = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to strip all '\"'-characters:

```
void stripquotes(char *ptr) {
    char *ptr2 = ptr;
    do {
        *ptr2 = *ptr++;
         if (*ptr2 != '\"')
             ptr2++;
    } while (*ptr);
}
```